# How to use "+" in javascript

Tags: javascript

when i input 1 in #weeksinayear and 2 in #leaveweeks i get and answer of 12 which is wrong. Any help? Same applies when i enter maybe 30 at #weeksinayear and 10 at #leaveweeks i will get an answer of 3010.

```
<input type='text' id='weeksinayear'/>
<input type='text' id='leaveweeks'/>
<input type='text' id='totalweeksperyear'/>

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#weeksinayear").keyup(function(){

        var weeksinayear = $("#weeksinayear").val();
        var leaveweeks = $("#leaveweeks").val();

      if(weeksinayear == ""){
                  var totalweeksperyear = $("#totalweeksperyear").val("");

      }else if(leaveweeks == ""){

                  var totalweeksperyear = $("#totalweeksperyear").val("");

      }else{

          var cal =  (weeksinayear) + (leaveweeks);

          var totalweeksperyear = $("#totalweeksperyear").val(cal);

      }


});
});
```

Comment: `.val()` returns strings ... `+` concatenates strings ... you want those strings to be numbers ... use unary + or parseInt or ParseFloat or Number

Comment: In order to understand why this is happening, you need to understand variable types. In short you are grabbing the value from a text field, which by default will be of type `string`. And you are trying to sum both of these, but that's not going to work, because they have to either be of type `int` or `number` or any other type that can be used for calculations. That's why you first need to convert `string` to `int` with for instance `parseInt()` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt . Also make sure to understand concept of `radix`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use parseInt()

Change the line to this

```
var totalweeksperyear = $("#totalweeksperyear").val(parseInt(weeksinayear,10) + parseInt(leaveweeks,10));
```

Comment: looks fine to me.

Comment: It works fine. Thanks. my question here again is what is the figure 10 doing?

Comment: Thats an optional value, represents a number (from 2 to 36) that represents the numeral system to be used ( Decimal, Hex, Oct etc ).  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp